# R :histogram of 100 exponential numbers with mean=10 & do the same thing 50 times

Tags: r

(a) I have to make a histogram of 100 exponential numbers with mean=10 and estimate the median

(b)again  I have to do the same thing 50 times as (a) and find a vector exp such that

```
   exp <- ifelse(mean<median, 1,0)
```

My attempt :

```
   a=rexp(100,10)
   hist(a)

   #estimating median
   median(a)
   boxplot(a)

   # repeating (a) 50 times
   for(i in 1:50){
```

Then i don't know what to do .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for. You have to initialize the vector and make room for storing the items if you want to use a for loop.

```
results <- 1:50    # initialize
for (i in 1:50) {
  a <- rexp(100,10)
  results[i] <- ifelse(mean(a) < median(a), 1, 0)
}

results
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

But this is much cleaner:

```
results <- sapply(1:50, function(x) {a <- rexp(100,10); mean(a) < median(a)} )
```

Note that the testing whether `mean(a) < median(a)` will produce a `TRUE` if true, and `FALSE` if false. These are numerically equal to 1 and 0 respectively (so you do not need the `ifelse`)

E.g. `1 == TRUE` yields `TRUE`, `0` == `FALSE` yields `TRUE`

If you want to specifically have 0 or 1 "visually", then you could use `(mean(a) < median(a)) * 1`

Comment: I think he is supposed to compare the mean of each of the 50 sample vectors with the median of the first sample vector.

Comment: No, it doesn't, seems somewhat like a homework assignment where he is supposed to see how often the median exceeds the mean for the given distribution.

Comment: @fotNelton It says "repeat (a)" 50 times, that would include drawing new distributions and testing whether the mean is lower than the median?

Comment: The mean of the 50 samples will be compared with the mean of the 50 median sample. So Dualinity is right.

Comment: @user2983722 If it is a correct/helpful answer you might consider accepting it :-)

Answer (score 1):

you mean like this?

```
sapply(1:50, function(x) {a <- rexp(100,10); 
                          b <- ifelse(mean(a) < median(a), 1,0)
                          pdf(paste0(x,"hist.pdf"))
                          boxplot(a)
                          dev.off()
                          return(b)
                          }
                          )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good opportunity to use `replicate`.

```
replicate(50,
          {a <- rexp(100,10);
           (mean(a) < median(a)) * 1
           })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
randSamples <- split(rexp(100*50, 1/10), 1:50)
unlist(lapply(randSamples, function(x) ifelse(mean(x) < median(x), 1, 0)))
```

**Want to learn how to fish for yourself?**

In R, you can keep these vectors of random integers separated, while still keeping them within the one object, by using a list. The following line creates 50*100 random numbers, and splits them into 50 samples.

NB: In R, if you want to make a sample with mean of 10, the second argument must be 1/mean, i.e.  rexpr(N, 1/mean).

```
randSamples <- split(rexp(100*50, 1/10), 1:50)
```

You can access each item in the list (which is in this case, a sample of 50) one at a time by indexing with [[i]]:

```
randSamples[[1]]
```

Or you can run loop through them as follows:

```
for (i in 1:50){
    mean(randSamples[[i]])
}
```

But you can more elegantly use the command lapply() to perform an operation over each item in the list, e.g.:

```
lapply(randSamples, median)
lapply(randSamples, mean)
```

Hence to perform the mean < median operation you would like, you can write a function within lapply. Then to join the list items for easier handling, you can use unlist:

```
unlist(lapply(randSamples, function(x) ifelse(mean(x) < median(x), 1, 0)))
```